# Слетает авторизация Yii2 (знаю, было, не помогло)

Tags: php, yii2

Суть в следующем. Создал проект, все стандартно. Настроен RBAC, в форме логина и пароля все проходит, вижу себя залогиненым. Но стоит просто обновить страницу или перейти куда-либо, как-будто и не авторизовался.

Ответ искал, много чего перечитал, но решения не нашел. Подскажите, что не так с кодом?

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use Yii;
use yii\behaviors\TimestampBehavior;
use yii\db\ActiveRecord;
use yii\web\IdentityInterface;
/**
 * This is the model class for table "user".
 *
 * @property int $id
 * @property string $username
 * @property string $email
 * @property string $password
 * @property string $auth_key
 */
class User extends ActiveRecord implements IdentityInterface
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'user';
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['username', 'email', 'password', 'auth_key'], 'required'],
            [['username', 'email', 'password', 'auth_key'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'id' => 'ID',
            'username' => 'Username',
            'email' => 'Email',
            'password' => 'Password',
            'auth_key' => 'Auth Key',
        ];
    }

    public function beforeSave($insert)
    {
        if (parent::beforeSave($insert)) {
            if ($this->isNewRecord) {
                $this->auth_key = \Yii::$app->security->generateRandomString();
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static function findIdentity($id)
    {
        return isset(self::$users[$id]) ? new static(self::$users[$id]) : null;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function findIdentityByAccessToken($token, $type = null)
    {
        foreach (self::$users as $user) {
            if ($user['accessToken'] === $token) {
                return new static($user);
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Finds user by username
     *
     * @param string $username
     * @return static|null
     */
    public static function findByUsername($username)
    {
        return static::findOne(['username' => $username]);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getAuthKey()
    {
        return $this->auth_key;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function validateAuthKey($auth_key)
    {
        return $this->auth_key === $auth_key;
    }

    /**
     * Validates password
     *
     * @param string $password password to validate
     * @return bool if password provided is valid for current user
     */

    public function setPassword($password) {
        $hash = Yii::$app->security->generatePasswordHash($password);
    }

    public function validatePassword($password)
    {
        return Yii::$app->security->validatePassword($password, $this->password);
    }

    public function generateAuthKey() 
    {
        $this->auth_key = Yii::$app->security->generateRandomString();
    }
}
```

LoginForm.php

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use Yii;
use yii\base\Model;

/**
 * LoginForm is the model behind the login form.
 *
 * @property User|null $user This property is read-only.
 *
 */
class LoginForm extends Model
{
    public $username;
    public $password;
    public $rememberMe = true;

    private $_user = false;


    /**
     * @return array the validation rules.
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            // username and password are both required
            [['username', 'password'], 'required'],
            // rememberMe must be a boolean value
            ['rememberMe', 'boolean'],
            // password is validated by validatePassword()
            ['password', 'validatePassword'],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Validates the password.
     * This method serves as the inline validation for password.
     *
     * @param string $attribute the attribute currently being validated
     * @param array $params the additional name-value pairs given in the rule
     */
    public function validatePassword()
    {
        $user = $this->getUser();
        if (!$user || !$user->validatePassword($this->password)) {
            $this->addError('password', 'Incorrect username or password.');
        }
    }

    /**
     * Logs in a user using the provided username and password.
     * @return bool whether the user is logged in successfully
     */
    public function login()
    {
        if ($this->validate()) {
            return Yii::$app->user->login($this->getUser(), $this->rememberMe ? 3600*24*30 : 0);
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Finds user by [[username]]
     *
     * @return User|null
     */
    public function getUser()
    {
        if ($this->_user === false) {
            $this->_user = User::findByUsername($this->username);
        }

        return $this->_user;
    }
}
```

Controller

```
<?php

namespace app\controllers;

use Yii;
use yii\filters\AccessControl;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\web\Response;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;
use app\models\LoginForm;
use app\models\ContactForm;

class SiteController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'access' => [
                'class' => AccessControl::className(),
                'only' => ['logout'],
                'rules' => [
                    [
                        'actions' => ['logout'],
                        'allow' => true,
                        'roles' => ['@'],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            'verbs' => [
                'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                'actions' => [
                    'logout' => ['post'],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function actions()
    {
        return [
            'error' => [
                'class' => 'yii\web\ErrorAction',
            ],
            'captcha' => [
                'class' => 'yii\captcha\CaptchaAction',
                'fixedVerifyCode' => YII_ENV_TEST ? 'testme' : null,
            ],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Displays homepage.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        return $this->render('index');
    }

    /**
     * Login action.
     *
     * @return Response|string
     */
    public function actionLogin()
    {
        if (!Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
            return $this->render('login');
        }

        $model = new LoginForm();
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->login()) {
            return $this->render('index');
        }

        $model->password = '';
        return $this->render('login', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Logout action.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function actionLogout()
    {
        Yii::$app->user->logout();

        return $this->goHome();
    }

    /**
     * Displays contact page.
     *
     * @return Response|string
     */
    public function actionContact()
    {
        $model = new ContactForm();
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->contact(Yii::$app->params['adminEmail'])) {
            Yii::$app->session->setFlash('contactFormSubmitted');

            return $this->refresh();
        }
        return $this->render('contact', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Displays about page.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function actionAbout()
    {
        return $this->render('about');
    }
}
```

Web.php

```
<?php

$params = require __DIR__ . '/params.php';
$db = require __DIR__ . '/db.php';

$config = [
    'id' => 'basic',
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
    'bootstrap' => ['log'],
    'aliases' => [
        '@bower' => '@vendor/bower-asset',
        '@npm'   => '@vendor/npm-asset',
    ],
    'components' => [
        'request' => [
            // !!! insert a secret key in the following (if it is empty) - this is required by cookie validation
            'cookieValidationKey' => 'DPDd0kq_NYd4E7EQcPW9w9zg_UVdvMji',
        ],
        'cache' => [
            'class' => 'yii\caching\FileCache',
        ],
        'authManager' => [
            'class' => 'yii\rbac\DbManager',
        ],
        'user' => [
            'identityClass' => 'app\models\User',
            'enableAutoLogin' => true,
        ],
        'errorHandler' => [
            'errorAction' => 'site/error',
        ],
        'mailer' => [
            'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
            // send all mails to a file by default. You have to set
            // 'useFileTransport' to false and configure a transport
            // for the mailer to send real emails.
            'useFileTransport' => true,
        ],
        'log' => [
            'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 3 : 0,
            'targets' => [
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                    'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'db' => $db,
        'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'rules' => [
            ],
        ],
    ],
    'params' => $params,
];

if (YII_ENV_DEV) {
    // configuration adjustments for 'dev' environment
    $config['bootstrap'][] = 'debug';
    $config['modules']['debug'] = [
        'class' => 'yii\debug\Module',
        // uncomment the following to add your IP if you are not connecting from localhost.
        //'allowedIPs' => ['127.0.0.1', '::1'],
    ];

    $config['bootstrap'][] = 'gii';
    $config['modules']['gii'] = [
        'class' => 'yii\gii\Module',
        // uncomment the following to add your IP if you are not connecting from localhost.
        //'allowedIPs' => ['127.0.0.1', '::1'],
    ];
}

return $config;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
'user' => [
            'identityClass' => 'app\models\User',
            'enableAutoLogin' => false,
            'authTimeout' => 60 * 60 * 24 * 100
```